# How to intepretate three paragraphs in my contract?

Tags: contract-law, labor-law, interpretation

I am a seaman and I have a work contract undersigned by both sides. In mentioned contract I have a paragraph saying, that:

> The payslip and balance payment will be forwarded after
> evaluation of the work hour protocols until the 15th of the following
> month.

Another paragraph:

> For every day on board (24h), the crew member is entitled to 0,5 days
> leave/holiday (12h).

And in next paragraph it is written, that:

> The seaman is entitled to paid leave in accordance with legal
> regulations of §§ 56 to 64 of the German Maritime Labour Act. The
> calendar year is the basis for the calculation of working days and
> times off. Place of vacation as per the meaning of the German Maritime
> Labour Act is the hometown of the crew member.

Correct me, please, if I am wrong, but as I unserstand well, for `leave/holiday` money I should wait until the end of the year? Or 15th of each following month?

In first case, if the contract does not mention this, when should I have to be paid for `leave/holiday`?
Thank you in advance for your interpretation.

Comment: Could you post a link to (or reproduce the sections of) the German Maritime Labour Act? It can be in German or English. The terms of the Act would be decisive for making sense of the clause.

Comment: @IñakiViggers here you go: https://www.ilo.org/dyn/natlex/docs/ELECTRONIC/94492/110910/F278052272/DEU94492%20Eng.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for leave/holiday money I should wait until the end of the year? Or 15th of each following month? when should I have to be paid for leave/holiday?

Although the Act is not entirely clear on *when* you would be entitled for paid leave, it is safe to rule out the interpretation of "*15th of each following month*".

Section 56(1) provides that "*[a] crew member shall be entitled to paid leave for each year of employment*". This suggests that entitlement will be computed on a yearly basis, not monthly. Likewise, this provision supersedes a possible interpretation that the clause considers the end of calendar year (i.e., the 31st of December) to be the cut-off date. In reality, this and other sections of the Act reflect that the criterion for entitlement is the completion of the year of employment.

That being said, section 58(1) seems a bit inconsistent in that it provides earliest [requested] leave "*where possible after six months' [sic] uninterrupted service on board*", thereby reducing *de facto* the time for entitlement as outlined in section 56(1) upon crew member's request.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding section 58, I belive, that paragraps of my contract: `The seaman works on (VESSEL NAME) from 04.06.2020.` and `The contract of hire will end on 15.07.2020 without a need of a written termination.` they covers matter of "where possible after six months' [sic] uninterrupted service on board", where after `15.07.2020` I should start my `leave/holiday`. Or I am wrong? ANd doeas it bring a new light for the matter when I should be paid for `leave/holiday`?

Comment: @bakunet I'm not sure I understood your comment. Do you mean that the duration of your employment will be less than a month and a half (from 04.06 to 15.07 of same year)?

Comment: That is correct. But it is normal in the shipping industry, where you are employed 24h/7. Like in the contract: `For every day on board (24h), the crew member is entitled to 0,5 days leave/holiday (12h).` So my concern is, that my `leave/holiday` starts after mid of July, and when should I be paid for my holiday time.

Comment: @bakunet That certainly changes things. Section 56(2) refers to the Federal Leave Act, of which [section §5(1)(b)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/burlg/__5.html) addresses scenarios where employment has been terminated before the statutory 6-month period (see [Wartezeit](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/burlg/__4.html)) elapses. In that case, the criterion of "*15th of the following month*" is more consistent with section §5(1) of the Bundesurlaubgesetz.

Comment: So in this case, if employment will be terminated 15.07.2020, following criterion _"15th of the following month"_ , _leave/holiday_ money supposed to be paid before the 15th day of August? Is it correct?

Comment: @bakunet Yes, 15th of August would be the latest. The short duration of your employment makes me wonder whether the paid leave you accrue in June ought to be reflected on 15.07.2020 even though employment began on the 4th of June and not the 1st. Regardless, July vs. August makes little difference when compared to "end of calendar year".

Comment: Thank you again for your point of view. It is very helpful. I found out that the company where I work now pays its employees very irregularly, often delaying the payment of wages or not paying the whole amount. So I am at the stage of arming myself with ammunition which I can fire on them after 15.07, although it may be more convenient for me after 15.08 to claim the full remuneration for June and July. Anyway, I wasn't sure if I would be able to claim my salary and holidays after August 15, or only for my basic salary. But I understand that I will be entitled to the whole, right?

Comment: @bakunet "*I will be entitled to the whole, right?*" Yes, that's correct. You will need to bring up the sections I mentioned from Bundesurlaubgesetz to support the argument that on August 15 of this year you are entitled to your base salary as well as the corresponding paid leave.

Comment: Allright, where should I send you bank check? ;)